# What is the evidence that that types are more basic specifications, and specifications are more detailed types?

Tags: functional-programming

In the book **Type Theory and Functional Programming** [[Thompson, S 1999]](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/) the author explains the relationship between specifications, types and proofs of functions:

> The equivalent specifications can be thought of as suggesting different program development methods: using the ∃∀ form, we develop the function and its proof as separate entities, either separately or together, whilst in the ∀∃ form we extract a function from a proof, post hoc.
>
> This analysis of specifications makes it clear that when we seek a program to meet a specification, we look for the first component of a member of an existential type; the second proves that the program meets the constraint part of the specification.

On this same topic, [the commenter writes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/21332/1709):

> Specifications are in a way "more detailed" types. Or, state the other way, types are more basic specifications. [Martin-Lof type theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory) is precisely about fusing the two ideas into one.

My question is: **What is the evidence that that types are more basic specifications, and specifications are more detailed types?**

Comment: What definition of *types* and *specifications* are you starting from? (I don't have Thompson's book.) I would define them as synonyms with different connotations, which would make the statement you want evidence for a tautology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gilles points out, it depends on what you count as types. If you mean by types something like
types in Java or Scala or Haskell, then this is clearly true.

One easy way to see this is (simplifying a bit) to use a general framework of
specifications to express the behavioural content of types as a
specific case of specification. The best framework to do this at the
moment is $\pi$-calculus as a programming language and [Hennessy-Milner
logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hennessy%E2%80%93Milner_logic) as a specification language. I suggest to choose [$\pi$-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus)
because it's expressive, and well studied. In particular, most
sequential programming languages are easily seen to be (behaviourally
equivalent to) specific sub-calculi of $\pi$-calculus.  Hennessy-Milner
logic is an expressive modal logic that can be used to nail down
processes up to behavioural equivalence.  Now we take an arbitarty
type, say the function space constructor
$
   int \rightarrow bool
$
and express the constraints this type imposes on programs as a
specification in Hennessy-Milner logic.

Conversely, we need to show that specifications are strictly more
expressive than types but that's fairly obvious, for we cannot specify
e.g. that a method is sorting its input array.